# Python - How to profile an infinite loop in multiple threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, profiler

Basically I have a routing protocol written in python that I need to run a few instances of in order to test some results. The protocol was hastily written by someone else, pretty messy code in places, poorly documented. The problem is, this drains my cpu. Everything slows down to a crawl when more than 2 instances are running. I would like to be able to profile everything and see where the bottlenecks arise.

I've read up on a few recommended profiles like cprofile. However, I'm not sure where to start. The protocol loops continuously. The threading was implemented in a way that I cannot escape out with ctrl-c. What is the best way tackle this? Any suggestions? There are a few places that I imagine are causing the problem. I may just end up cleaning those up, but I'm still curious of the best way to profile something like this. In the past, everything I've had to profile had a set start and finish.

Comment: If you use an IDE like PyCharm, it has: http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/05/pycharm-4-5-eap-build-141-988-introducing-python-profiler/

Comment: Have you tried with `prof = cProfile.Profile()` `prof.run('your_routing_protocol')`, after a while Ctrl+C, `prof.print_stats()`?

Comment: @Mr.E As in from an interactive python terminal? Just tried it, and it appears to be working. I just need to sort/interpret the data. I'm still open to other ideas about how to go about this.